# how to get sets of information from a database ( eg results 1-24, 25-49 etc )

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching all over Google and cant seem to come up with the right answer yet ( I'm just probably not searching the correct terms ), I'm trying to get 25 results returned from a database each time but for example what I want to do is:

query 1 should return results 1 - 24

query 2 should return results 25 - 49

and so on.

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: separate queries using LIMIT

Comment: but can i limit from say the 25th result to the 49th result?

Comment: yes, you can have two terms in the limit clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are separate queries althought they return the exact same fields from the exact same tables under the exact same conditions. The difference between them is the LIMIT chunk:

```
LIMIT startRow, rowsCount
--the first row is the 0th, not 1st.
```

If your query is like:

```
select * from mytable where field1 = "value1"
```

you must execute **two separate queries** (or as much queries as you want):

```
select * from mytable where field1 = "value1" LIMIT 0, 25
-- will return the first 25 rows

select * from mytable where field1 = "value1" LIMIT 25, 25
-- will return 25 rows starting from the row 25
```

general formula: If you want to fetch a specific page N (starting from 1), where each page has M elements, you must append to your query:

```
$yourquery = "select * from mytable where myfield = 'myvalue'";
$yourquery .= sprintf(" LIMIT %d, %d", ($page-1)*$itemsPerPage, $itemsPerPage);
$result = mysql_query($yourquery, $yourconnection);
```

**Disclaimers**:

- mysql_ is deprecated. use mysqli_ instead.
- never use, in real production code, `sprintf` for your parameters unless you know what are you doing, since you could expose a SQL Injection hole.

**Edit** You can use ANY elements you want to do LIMIT. Usually, pages have constant size, but since you want irregular sizes (page 1 24 elements, page 2 25 elements, you should) use the following `LIMIT`s:

```
LIMIT 0, 24
--gets the first 24 (say 1st to 24th) elements

LIMIT 24, 25
--gets the following 25 items (say 25th to 49th)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 0,25 // This will give you 1-24 records
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 25,25 // This will give you 25-49 records
```

Comment: Your second query will return rows 26 to 75.

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15
> ```

So in your case:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 0,25
SELECT * FROM `table_name` LIMIT 25,25
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
LIMIT 0,24)
UNION 
(SELECT * 
FROM 
mytable 
LIMIT 24,25)
ORDER BY someSortOfId;
```

Note that there should be at least one column with unique values (such as an ID), or the result sets will overlap.

Comment: Your first query returns rows 1 to 23, the second returns 25 to 72.